# Como puedo pasar de C++ a Python?

Tags: python, c++, c

Tengo esté código en c, sobre las tablas de verdad y me gustaría migrarlo a python3, alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Estuve intentando algo así, pero en la función imprimir hay un error que no logro identificar, por lo tanto el resultado que arroja es incorrecto

```
import numpy as np
 
def imprimir(num, holder):
  i = int(num)-1
  while(i!=0):
    if(((np.right_shift(holder,i))& 1)==1):
      print("V")
    else:
      print("F")
    i-=1
    
  if(((np.right_shift(holder,0))& 1)==1):
    print("V")
  else:
    print("F")

def calcular(num):

    total = np.uint64(1)<<np.uint64(num)
    holder = 0

    while(total != 0):
        imprimir(num, holder)
        total-=1
 
def inicio():
  num = input("ingrese la cantidad de variables \n")
  calcular(num)
```

Este sería el input

> Ingrese la cantidad de variables
> 2

Este sería el output (Función imprimir)

> T
> F
> T
> F
> T
> F
> T
> F

[image: REs Py]

Este es el código completo en C++

```
#include <cstdlib>
 
using namespace std;
 
void calcular(unsigned int*);
void imprimir(unsigned int*, unsigned long int*);
 
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 
    //Valor máximo 31, i. e. 31 variables
    unsigned int num = 0;
 
    cout<<"Ingrese un número: ";
    cin>>num;
    cout<<endl;
 
    calcular(&num);
 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 
}
 
void calcular(unsigned int* num) {
    //potencia de 2, total de impresiones
    unsigned long total = (1 << *num);
    //registro de hasta 32 bits
    unsigned long int holder = 0;
 
    while(total != 0) {
 
        imprimir(num, &holder);
 
        //incrementar el valor en el registro
        holder++;
        //decrementar las impresiones
        total--;
 
    }
 
}
 
void imprimir(unsigned int* num, unsigned long int* holder) {
 
    //para impresión, valor máximo 31   
    register unsigned int i;
    //asignar el número de bits-1  
    i = (*num)-1;
    //mientras el numero de bits no es 0
    while (i!=0) {
        //comprobar el bit e imprimir V o F
        cout <<((((*holder) >> i) & 1) == 1 ? "V" : "F")<<" ";
        //decrementa i
        i--;
    }
 
    //imprimir el bit 0
    cout <<((((*holder) >> 0) & 1) == 1 ? "V" : "F")<<" ";
 
    cout<<endl;
 
}
```

Este sería el resultado del codigo en c++

[image: Resultado del codigo en c++]

Muchas gracias por su ayuda
.................................................................................................

Comment: En Python `and` es equivalente a `&&`. Si quieres operar con bits, usas `& igual que en C. También te falta el `print` delante de `("V")` en la misma función. Hay demasiados problemas con el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Python la vida es más simple:

```
num = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de variables: "))
for i in range(2 ** num):
    linea = bin(i)[2:].rjust(num, '0')
    print (linea.replace('0','V ').replace('1', 'F '))
```

Dado el número de variables `num`, la tabla de verdad contendra `2 ** num` filas, que puedo recorrer con `for i in range(2 ** num):`. Con esto, la variable `i` recorre desde 0 hasta 2 ** num - 1.

La cosa es tomar el valor binario de `i` como una línea de la tabla de verdad, donde los ceros corresponde a `V` y los unos a `F`.

Ejemplo: el binario 00101 es la representación de VVFVF.

La función `bin` me retorna un string con la representación en binario del valor.

Ejemplo: `bin(5)` retorna '0b101'.

Pero solo me interesan los ceros y unos. En Python se usa la *rebanada* de listas y strings. Para obtener desde el tercer caracter en adelante, uso `[2:]`.

Ejemplo: `'0b101'[2:]` retorna '101'.

Con la función `rjust(largo, relleno)` puedo ajustar el string al largo deseado, rellenando por la izquierda con el caracter especificado:

```
linea = bin(i)[2:].rjust(num, '0')
```

y sólo me queda reemplazar los '0' por 'V ' y los '1' por 'T ':

```
print (linea.replace('0','V ').replace('1', 'F '))
```

#### Demo

produce:

```
Ingrese la cantidad de variables: 3
V V V 
V V F 
V F V 
V F F 
F V V 
F V F 
F F V 
F F F 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import numpy as np

    def imprimir(num, holder):
      i = int(num)-1
      while(i!=0):
        if(((np.right_shift(holder,i))& 1)==1):
          print("V", end=" ")
        else:
          print("F", end=" ")
        i-=1
    
      if(((np.right_shift(holder,0))& 1)==1):
        print("V")
      else:
        print("F")
  
    def calcular(num):

        total = np.uint64(1)<<np.uint64(num)
        holder = 0

        while(total != 0):
            imprimir(num, holder)
            holder += 1
            total-=1
 
    def inicio():
      num = input("ingrese la cantidad de variables   ")
      print(" ")
      calcular(num)
```

Comment: Y esto es......?